# Failed to run ListView library?

Tags: java, android, listview, horizontalscrollview

using library [HORIZONTAL LISTVIEW library](https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView).it was working fine yesterday but creating issue today dnt know what happended ? i have followed everything as it is:but i m getting error on runtime in line
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.linearlistview.R$attr
            at com.linearlistview.LinearListView.(LinearListView.java:24)**
i have simple use this in xml :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_videoname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first heading text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
        android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_topheadingfontsize"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/infotab_secondtextview_margintop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="second heading text"
        android:textColor="@color/infotab_secondheading_foncolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_secondheadingfontsize" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_marginbottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_margintop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_country"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="country name"
            android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_fontsize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/videodetail_edit_marginright"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="30 jul,15"
            android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_fontsize" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_videodetail"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videodetail_tabs"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayout_viewerscount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_marginbottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_margintop"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
            android:layout_weight="0.32">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_viewerscount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:src="@drawable/viewer_icon"

               />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_viewerscount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/videodetail_edit_marginright"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="1996"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageview_viewerscount"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_viewerscount"
                android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textview_followers_fontsize" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayout_loved"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_marginbottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_margintop"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
            android:layout_weight="0.32">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_loved"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:src="@drawable/love_icon"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_loved"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/videodetail_edit_marginright"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageview_loved"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_loved"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="1996"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textview_followers_fontsize" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayout_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_marginbottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/infotab_textviewcountry_margintop"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
            android:layout_weight="0.32">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:src="@drawable/share_icon"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_share"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/videodetail_edit_marginright"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageview_share"


                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_share"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Share"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textview_followers_fontsize" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_videodetailbelow"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videodetail_tabs"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlayout_userprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/infotab_rlayout_userprofile_margintop"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/infotab_rlayout_userprofile_margintop">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_userrprofile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/infotab_imageview_userrprofile_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/infotab_imageview_userrprofile_height"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:background="@drawable/border"

            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayout_userinfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_userrprofile">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textview_username_fontsize"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="username"
            android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_totalfollowerscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textview_followers_fontsize"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="1595 followers"
            android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_topheading_fontcolor"
            />
</LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_followprofile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_follow"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/videodetail_edit_marginright"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_videodetailbottom"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videodetail_tabs"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_viewmore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View More"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/videodetail_backarrow_marginleft"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/infotab_textview_viewmore_margintop"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/infotab_textview_viewmore_marginbottom"
        android:textSize="@dimen/infotab_textview_viewmore_fontsize"
        android:textColor="@color/infotab_textview_viewmore_fontcolor"/>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.linearlistview.LinearListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_morevideos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="none"
        />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and added in gradle :    compile 'com.github.frankiesardo:linearlistview:1.0.1@aar'
but my logcat error is here :

```
Process: com.bcast, PID: 11078
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.linearlistview.R$attr
        at com.linearlistview.LinearListView.<clinit>(LinearListView.java:24)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
        at com..bcast.ui.fragments.InfoFragment.onCreateView(InfoFragment.java:72)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17437)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5381)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5381)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5381)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5381)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17437)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5381)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2297)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1401)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1259)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6521)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
at
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to use the RecyclerView widget

Comment: no recyclerview inside scrollview is not working .... i m using scrollview and inside scrollview there should be some  listview that will show items like gallery